# Logical Issue/problem with pagination in feeds/posts page in nodeJs

Tags: node.js, pagination, feed, infinite-scroll, posts

I have a feeds page application in mern where users can follow other users to view the posts created by them. Now, while displaying the posts, I need to display the posts in descending order which means that the latest posts would be at the top. In front-end, I have an infinite scrolling implemented which means when the users scroll downs, next set of posts will be retrieved from the GET API. So, now here in the get API, there are two options, one is offset based pagination and the other is cursor based pagination. In these kind of scenarios, cursor based pagination suits well in order to avoid duplicated data in the front-end. But here in cursor based pagination, lets say, initially the cursor is null and so I receive top 10 latest posts and now my cursor becomes the date of the last received post. So, now when the users scrolls and makes an API call, the cursor is set and the next certain posts are received which has created At date less then the cursor.

Now, the big issue here is how to get the posts by other users which are just yet created while the user is scrolling down because when he calls the API, the posts will be retrieved having date less than the cursor, so how will we able to get the newly created posts in this case ?

I thought of some other approach like socket but I think it is not required because I just want the data on scroll through API and not in real time. This problem is like similar to how the feeds would work in social media applications like Instagram

Comment: A common solution is to display a message like "there a new posts" with a button for loading them which resets the cursor. Actually I don't see a big issue here because when the user scrolls down he wants to see older post and not the very recent ones.